# Does meteor direction change if you look from a different country?

Tags: untagged

So here is the question: Me and a friend of mine from Norway we saw a meteor but que said he saw it in the opposite direction as me and I was looking from Spain, does that make any sense? Or should we see it going the same direction?

Thanks in advance